# Lag when playing mic audio directly to output using web audio api

Tags: javascript, web, delay, web-audio-api, microphone

I simply want to play audio coming in the microphone directly to the output, using the code below. But there is a lag, about 0.2 seconds. Is there a way to reduce this delay ?

```js
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
    
var aCtx;
var analyser;
var microphone;
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
  navigator.getUserMedia(
    {audio: true}, 
    function(stream) {
      aCtx = new AudioContext();
      microphone = aCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
      var destination=aCtx.destination;
      microphone.connect(destination);
    },
    function(){ console.log("Error 003.")}
  );
}
```

Comment: Did you found any solution for this in the meanwhile?

Comment: Not really, I moved to Rust programming language. The web audio api has been rewrite in rust, and is available at https://crates.io/crates/web-audio-api
Rust is much more predictible than the browser, and latency is really low ! However it is a hard language, comparing to js.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable any pre-processing which should reduce the delay to a minimum.

Instead of this ...

```
navigator.getUserMedia({
    audio: true
})
```

... you would then write this ...

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: {
        autoGainControl: false,
        echoCancellation: false,
        noiseSuppression: false
    }
})
```

... to disable all pre-processing.

Please note that I also used `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` instead of `navigator.getUserMedia`. Usage of the latter is deprecated.

Comment: thanks, it reduced the delay, but there is still a perceptible lag... that makes the web audio api hard to use for my case, sad

Comment: The delay (latency) also depends on the browser and operating system. I think currently Firefox on macOS has the lowest possible latency.